# R Tensorflow installation with no user input in console

Tags: r, tensorflow, console

I have a basic script in R 4.1 and R Studio which installs TensorFlow 2.

When I run the library installation for Tensorflow, everything works fine with no issues. My issue is that when I call the library and run the install_tensorflow command, the console is asking me to answer a "yes/no" question.

Would you like to install Miniconda? [Y/n]:

My question: How do I answer this with a Y without having to type directly into the console? I want to just run an R Script to install and provision my conda environment without manual intervention. Programmatic User Input.

Here is my full R code:

install.packages("tensorflow")

library(tensorflow)

install_tensorflow(method="auto", conda="auto", version="2.0.0", envname ="tf_test")

Comment: Tensorflow R can be installed in several ways, few of the installation methods and instructions are given https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation/#installation-methods. Follow the instructions and install Tensorflow R on your system. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks but this isnt helpful to my question. I went to the page you linked and saw nothing new or related to my issue. The core question is related to the yes/no question and automating the response. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: That is bare minimum required to complete the Installation process.